# Url rewriting in tomcat without using third party api

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I'm trying out **URL rewriting** using tomcat without using third party API like **Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter**. Some of the forum says can't do without third party api in tomcat, but in tomcat 8 they are given provision for url rewriting.  I found [this url](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

Kindly advise me on this issue. Also provide some samples for url rewriting in tomcat.

Thanks for your time & response.

***Note***:- Don't go for the topic: **Url rewriting on tomcat through apache**, It's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of examples in the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) you linked in the original question. The rewrite capabilities in Tomcat 8 are brand-new and haven't gotten a great deal of testing in the wild, whereas the Tuckey filter has been used quite a bit.

(Note that Tomcat 8 is currently in beta phase as of today, 10 March 2014. It's fairly stable: Apache's JIRA instance has been running on it for a while, but YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! So we can't use tomcat 8 as of now?

Comment: Finally, I done with Tuckey api. If any one knows about url rewrite with tomcat api itself, kindly share it.

Comment: @Durai You can certainly use Tomcat 8, but just remember that it's not had an official stable release yet, and that includes the rewriting capabilities (as beta) as well.

Comment: @Durai If you want to configure something specific using Tomcat 8's rewriting capabilities, post your requirements and someone can probably give you a direct answer. Your original post didn't really ask a specific question.